# Is it Possible to Delete Songs from iCloud without iTunes Match?

Tags: itunes, ipad, icloud, music, itunes-match

**Edit in response to this question being a duplicate.** This is not a duplicate as I am asking how to delete any song from any artist off of cloud storage, not just U2's *Songs of Innocence*. The link given that provides the supposed answer will only delete the U2 album, *Songs of Innocence* from the cloud storage. Yes, *Songs of Innocence* prompted me to try and delete songs from the cloud storage, but I have additional songs I want deleted. I have already detailed in my question how that link does not help me, nor solve this question, as it only works for the one U2 album.

I recently used iPad to listen to some music only to find out I had U2's *Songs of Innocence* album. I wasn't too bothered until one of their songs started playing. I decided I would like to delete their album from both the iPad and the iCloud. Also there were a few other songs I had purchased prior that I wanted to delete from both my iPad and the iCloud. Here is the list of things I tired to accomplish this feat.

**1. I went online to see how to delete the album and was redirected here:**

itunes.com/soi-remove

But, there are other songs in on my iCloud that I have purchased and I would like to delete. Which leads to number two.

**2. I searched the web and found this:**

[How do you delete songs from Icloud on Iphone](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5343927?start=0&tstart=0)

Ultimately, the accepted answer in that thread was to do this:

Go to *Settings* > *iTunes & App* Stone and shut off *Music* under the *SHOW ALL* category.
and
Go to *Settings* > *Music* and shut off *Show All Music*.

That will hide the songs from your iPad (or other apple device) but it will not actually delete the songs from the iCloud. If I turn those settings back on, I will see those songs again.

**3. I found this:**

[Delete songs and music videos from your iTunes library with an iTunes Match subscription](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201323)

It details how to delete songs from the iCloud, but it requires iTunes Match and iTunes Match costs $24.99 a year. I'm not about to spend money to delete songs from iCloud that I purchased.

**4. I tried 3rd party software.**

I searched around the internet some more and ended up downloading the app *Document 5* on my iPad, but that app was unable to even see the song files on iCloud (although the app can view and delete other types of files stored on iCloud).

**5. I tried deleting the songs through my iCloud account.**

I tried signing into iCloud.com from my computer and yet again, there is no way to view songs on your iCloud through your iCloud.com account. I can view other files, like documents and photos, and I can delete them, but I can't view or delete song files.

**6. I searched apple.stackexchange.com and www.reddit.com/r/apple.**

Basically, this leads to the same answers. I need iTunes Match and that costs money.

---

I want to not only delete the U2 album, but also other songs on my iCloud. Yes, I will most likely use the link to delete the U2 album, but am I really expected to pay money or use a special service when I want to delete other songs from iCloud?

I would like to be able to have control over the music I purchase and there are some songs that I would like to delete for good and not just hide them from view, knowing that I can just re-download them off the cloud at a later date. However, it seems Apple has made it so I cannot view or modify my song files on iCloud without either purchasing an iTunes Match subscription or using the U2 album removal link (which will only work for that album). So, I ask:

**Is there any way to delete songs from iCloud without an iTunes Match subscription?**